# What is the meaning of "Feature X requires run-time support"?

Tags: c++

Quoting Bjarne Stroustrup's *C++ Programming Language* (4th ed., p. 15):

> Except for the `new`, `delete`, `typeid`, `dynamic_cast`, and `throw` operators, and the `try`-block, individual C++ expressions and statements need no run-time support. This can be essential for embedded and high-performance applications.

In what sense does `auto x = new int;` requires run-time support, while `auto x = 2 + 2;` does not? Naively, I thought the compiler simply converts either example to some object code. What makes the object code that creates an `int` object so conceptually different from the object code that does some bit arithmetic, that the former is said to "need run-time support"?

Further down on the same page some examples of run-time support are given (IIUC):

> There are, however, good reasons for using C++ in environments that provide significantly more run-time support. Facilities such as dynamic loading, incremental compilation, and a database of type definitions can be put to good use without affecting the language.

What language features don't work without these facilities?

Answer (score 4):

`new int` dynamically allocates memory. Which means that there must be a place to allocate memory *from*. That requires runtime support.

Oh yes, `auto x = 2 + 2;` allocates memory as well. But that is an automatic variable, not one whose lifetime is defined by the user explicitly deleting it. The storage for automatic (and static) variables may be limited by the implementation, but *some of it* is required to exist.

By contrast, you can write a C++ implementation that has no "free store", provides no place to allocate memory from.

It should also be noted that Stroustrup is primarily talking about `::operator new` and `::operator delete`. Placement `new` does not require runtime support.

---

In a broader sense of the term, what Stroustrup means when he says "runtime support" is something that effectively needs to call a function at runtime. It's not necessarily actually calling a function, but it's doing something that is very much like calling a function.

For example, `static_cast`ing to a derived class from a base class requires nothing more than a pointer offset. The offset value is statically defined at compile time. At runtime, all that happens is that you add a register to a constant value.

`dynamic_cast`ing requires reading a lot of runtime data and walking compiler-generated data structures. That is effectively a function call, even if it doesn't look like one (though it kinda does). And it certainly has the performance characteristics of one.

Throwing/catching exceptions is a complex process that has to interact with a number of elements, some of which can be part of the underlying operating environment.

Comment: Well, a function call requires a new stack frame. That means there must be a stack available - how is it any different from a heap being available?

Comment: @max The C++ language specification (afaik) does not specifically name "the stack" and "the heap" (only the abstract terms "automatic storage" and "free store") - other alternative exotic approaches could be used. And you can use C without a heap if you're comfortable with static buffers.

Comment: @max: Having `main` execute at all requires a stack. Or where do you think `main` gets its parameters from? Since you have at least that much of a stack, the question for subsidiary function calls is how much of a stack you have.

Comment: @max Variables can be allocated on the stack simply by incrementing or decrementing a processor register. Allocating/deallocating  memory dynamically cannot be done simply with a few machine code instructions.

Comment: @dai So "automatic storage" (usually, but not necessarily, the stack) is assumed to always exist? OTOH, the "free store" (usually, but not necessarily, the heap) is not assumed to always exist, so allocating memory from it implies we're relying on run-time support?

Comment: @NicolBolas I understand it makes no sense to not have the stack; but (in my limited experience) not having a heap also makes no sense. So you're saying there are environments without a heap, but no environments without a stack? (I don't disagree, it's just I'm too used to a traditional OS environment that has both.)

Comment: @NeilButterworth so there's some accepted "lowest common denominator" of usable CPU architecture, which includes a stack pointer (with the right semantics)? And anything beyond that (whether implemented in the CPU or by the OS) would be considered run-time, right?

Comment: @max: An environment where a compiler cannot implement a stack is an environment that doesn't have *memory* at all. Also, see the update to my answer.

Comment: @max Well, the C++ Standard doesn't  address issues like that, but practically, allocating automatic or static variables doesn't need library support, but allocating dynamically does.

Comment: I used an implementation once that didn't use a stack for function parameters

Comment: @NicolBolas Ah, so perhaps the run-time support is defined (largely or even entirely) in terms of "hidden" costs? In that, most C++ operations have very small and predictable cost. OTOH, a handful of C++ operations have a materially higher cost, either due to the required system calls or due to the relatively sophisticated internal implementation. And performance-critical apps may run in an environment that doesn't support the second type of operations? Then the boundary is defined by practical considerations rather than by some fundamental logical distinction.

Comment: @M.M What was the memory model?

Comment: @max something very haphazard